# Ample line bundle gives alternative description of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles, ample-bundles, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a (smooth) projective variety (over $\mathbb{C}$), and $\mathcal{L}$ an ample line bundle on $X$. I have heard that then

$$ X \cong \mathrm{Proj} \left( \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k}) \right)$$

but I am not sure how to prove this or if this is even an equivalent definition of ampleness. Can anybody provide an explanation or a reference?

Comment: Proposition 28.26.13 in the Stacks project — note that since $X$ is projective, the open immersion $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Proj}(S) $ is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: @abx that is tag [01Q3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01Q3). The numbers are not stable; see also the [tags explained](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags) page.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn: Oh, OK, thanks! I am not too familiar with the Stacks project.